# How to bind context to React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a function that I call from a child component callback. I'm trying to access some state variable but variables are `undefined`. I think the issue is when the child component callback the function context it not bind to the parent component. How to do this.

It is sure that myVariable is set before myFunciton is called.

```
const MyParentView = props => {

   const[myVariable, setMyVariable] = useState(undefined)

   const onTextFieldChange = val => {
       setMyVariable(val)
   }

   const myFunction = () => {
       // myVariable is set to some value by this time
       console.log(myVariable)
       // But it logs undefined
   }

   return (
      <Input onChange={e => onTextFieldChange(e.target.value)}
      <MyChildComponent getData={()=>myFunction()}/>
   )
}
```

Following is the child component ( The actual one )

```
// @flow

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { get } from "lodash"

type Props = {
  children: any,
  getData?: Function,
  threshold?: number
}

const InfiniteScroll = ({ children, getData, threshold = 0.9 }: Props) => {
  const listRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listRef.current) {
      const bottom = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
      const height =
        window.innerHeight || get(document, "documentElement.clientHeight")

      if (bottom <= height) {
        getData && getData()
      }
    }
  })

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const winScroll =
      get(document, "body.scrollTop") ||
      get(document, "documentElement.scrollTop")

    const height =
      get(document, "documentElement.scrollHeight") -
      get(document, "documentElement.clientHeight")

    const scrolled = winScroll / height
    if (scrolled >= threshold) {
      getData && getData()
    }
  }

  return <div ref={listRef}>{children}</div>
}

export default InfiniteScroll
```

Comment: Could you please include the code that sets `myVariable` value?

Comment: Sure. I'm simplifying the code so it might make no sense. But basically myFunction is  called on state variable change ( using userEffect ) to trigger a api call. That load data to a table. My child component is a infinite scroll which call the call back when user scrolled to the end. Where I need to trigger api for more data. That is when I found variable undefined.

Comment: Can you show how you use getData in child component, because problem in functional component  in your case in not because of context but because of closure

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a closure in your `myFunction` like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
      return function() {
       // myVariable is set to some value by this time
       console.log(myVariable)
       // But it logs undefined
      }
   }
```

Comment: Try passing the `myVariable` as a parameter to `myFunction`

Comment: Still it is empty.

Comment: See if [this](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb) helps.